# How to create one to one foreign key using FluentMigrator

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator, db-first

I'm using this code for creating foreign key:

```
Create.ForeignKey("FK_Table1_Table2")
    .FromTable("Table1").ForeignColumn("Table1_ID")
    .ToTable("Table2").PrimaryColumn("Table2_ID");
```

And as a result I have one to many relationship:

```
public class Table1
{
    public int Table1_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Table2 Table2 { get; set; }
}


public class Table2
{
    public Table2()
    {
        this.Tables1 = new HashSet<Table1>();
    }
    public int Table2_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Table1> Tables1 { get; set; }
}
```

but I want to see:

```
public class Table2
{
    public int Table2_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
}
```

Is there way to do that with using FluentMigrator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relational databases have no special notion for many/one to one FK relationship. The only way FK becomes "one" is if it also has unique constraint.

So I believe you should add something like this after foreign key creation code:

```
Create.UniqueConstraint()
    .OnTable("Table1").Column("Table1_ID");
```